# Are all deterministic functions free of side-effects (and vice versa)?

Tags: functional-programming, pure-function

I'm reading about pure-functions in functional programming and am wondering, whether a function being deterministic implies that the function is also side-effect free? (and vice versa?)

Comment: i'm guessing by deterministic you mean referentially transparent? but there are at least a couple of other things it could mean (particulalry in FP non-deterministic is sometimes used to mean returns a list of possible outcomes)

Comment: Yes I'm pretty certain referential transparency is what I meant. By deterministic I mean for example `sin()` (always returning the same output when given a particular input), so `sin(90)` can be substituted by 1

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Pure = deterministic + without side effects

A function is pure only, if both criteria are met. If it meets only one of them, it's not pure.

**Deterministic but with sideeffects:**

As pointed out by @Caleth

```
int DeterministicButSideeffects(int param)
{
    Console.Writeline("Sideeffect"); // Side effect here
    this.someVariable = param; // Another side effect

    return param; // Result only depends on the parameters
}
```

**Without sideeffects but not deterministic**

```
int NonDeterministicWithoutSideeffects(int param)
{
    return param + getRandomIntNumber(); // Result depends on random number
}
```

Note that side effects are only "outbound". If a function modifies the state of the containing code (global variable or field in a class) or if it performs some I/O-operations, it has side effects.

Another very simple function that is not deterministic would be:

```
DateTime GetCurrentDateTime()
{
    return DateTime.Now; // -> Result depends on current datetime
}
```

**Pure:**

```
int add(int num1, int num2)
{
    return num1 + num2;
}
```

Comment: arguably getting a random number does perform a side effect as it either does some IO (get some hardware measurement ) or modifies some global state (internal state of the prng)

Comment: @jk: It could read uninitialized memory which is likely not I/O proper. Even  if nothing else changes the contents of the uninitialized memory, the function will return the same result in further invocations, but the result will be unpredictable. It's still a dependence on an external process, that is, the physical process that flips bits of powered-off memory.

Comment: reading uninitialized is a spectacularly bad way to implement a prng. un-initialized memory is not guaranteed to be in anyway random

Comment: @jk correct. depending on the implementation of getRandomIntNumber(), side effects could happen (like changing state of the prng).

Comment: @9000 http://stackoverflow.com/a/31746063/207716 gives good reasons why you can't write a PRNG by just reading unitialized memory

Comment: @jk: not random (in any statistical sense), just unpredictable and not dependent on any inputs.

Comment: Given getting a random number does perform a side effect, is there a function without side effects but not deterministic?

Comment: a function getCurrentDate() would be without side-effects but not deterministic

Answer (score 4):

It's easy to show that a function being deterministic doesn't imply that it is pure, with a simple counterexample:

```
int DeterministicButNotPure(int param)
{
    Console.Writeline("Foo invoked"); // Side effect here
    return param; // Result only depends on the parameters
}
```

Comment: Ok, thank you. But All pure functions are deterministic, right?

Comment: This site is [about](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tour) conceptual questions and answers are expected to explain things. Throwing code dumps instead of explanation is like copying code from IDE to whiteboard: it may look familiar and even sometimes be understandable, but it feels weird... just weird. [Whiteboard doesn't have compiler](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5508110/839601)

Comment: @gnat this is a conceptual answer: it shows that the implication "function is deterministic" if and only if "function is pure" doesn't hold, by providing a counterexample: a simple function that is deterministic, but isn't pure

Comment: I think this sort of answer is helpful. However, it only answers one question but not if the opposite direction (Purity implies determinism) always holds.

Comment: @netik the definition of a pure function implies that. "A pure function is pure when it is deterministic and doesn't have side effects."